# updating task definition using Jenkins in aws ecs ec2

Tags: shell, jenkins, amazon-ecs

I have two tasks running in a single task definition (set up the desired count of that service to 2 ), I am using Jenkins for continuous deployment. When updating the service task, First I need to turn of the two running tasks.

I am trying to do this

First getting the current tasks using

```
def currentTask = sh (
      returnStdout: true,
      script:  " aws ecs list-tasks  --cluster ${clusterName} --family  ${taskFamily} --output text | egrep 'TASKARNS'| awk '{print \$2}' "
     ).trim()
```

Then stopping that task using

```
if (currentTask) {
sh "aws ecs stop-task --cluster ${clusterName} --task ${currentTask}"
}
```

but it is stopping only the first task. I have tried to write a "bash script" with for loop to iterate the "current task" variable but not working with the Jenkins format.

I tried using following script to stop the tasks  but its not working

```
 if (currentTask) {
 sh " 
       for oldtask in ${currentTask}; do
            aws ecs stop-task --cluster ${clusterName} --task ${oldtask};
       done "
   }
```

any idea how for use the "for loop" with Jenkins to stop both the running task?

Comment: Can you please provide the need for stopping tasks manually like above?. If you are looking for restarting all tasks for a given service then you can use `aws ecs update-service --cluster "myCluster" --service "myService" --desired-count 2 --force-new-deployment`

Comment: Its for CI/CD using Jenkins, when a new update is made on the code in the gitlab, its processed by jenkins, build the docker image then deploy it into the aws cluster. For that the running task should be stopped then update the new task definition and start the ECS service with the new task definition.

Answer (score 0):

I have to side with Imran's comment here -- normally you don't need to manually stop the tasks. If you update the service to a new definition, ECS will gracefully transition from tasks running the old definition to tasks running the new definition, smoothly with no downtime if it can (depending on some of your other settings). You shouldn't have to stop them.

If you really do want to stop them manually despite all that, then you're going to need to explain what "its not working" means. Are you getting an error message? If so, what? Is there any output during that part of the jenkins build?

Comment: Re >> "its not working" means the bash script with for loop is not processed by jenkins. I  planned to stop the running tasks first because of resource shortage. I found in some case when we increased the desired count of service, say from 2 to 4  due to insufficient memory in container instance, 2 task from old task definition and 2 task from new task definition may run.  It seems instead of stopping old task manually we can update the "Minimum healthy percent" to zero so that it will override the blue green deployment.

Comment: Seems likely that there's a deployment configuration that would suit your needs. If you have two tasks, try: 

"deploymentConfiguration": {
        "maximumPercent": 100,
        "minimumHealthyPercent": 50
    }  -- that should tell ECS to stop one, start one, wait for it to be healthy, stop the other, start another, wait for it to be healthy. Slow, but still blue-green without going over the resource limit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working bash script you can try. Since you are working with JSON responses out of CLI, so `jq` is best to work with but you can try with others. Please let me know how it goes on your end.

```
clusterName="myCluster"
taskFamily="myTaskFamily"
for task in $(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $clusterName --family ${taskFamily} | jq -r '.taskArns[]'); do
    aws ecs stop-task --cluster ${clusterName} --task ${task};
done
```

Note -

1. It's not in best practice stop tasks like this and as Geoffrey suggested, work with proper deployment configuration for better management.

Comment: yup, that should work via commandline, but let me see how it goes when we use it via Jenkins. Jenkins is using groovy format and its tricky when writing bash script.

Comment: @sandeepkrishna sure. It shouldn't be hard to put above shell in Jenkins Job or Pipeline scripts. If it works, please accept the answer.